# VBA Instantiating second of two classes in user form triggers terminate of first class

Tags: vba, class, userform

I can't seem to find any reason for this behavior ...

I have a user form where I'm instantiating two classes I've created, one which will be chucked into a collection.  When stepping through, once the code hits the `Initialize` sub of the second class the first class terminates.  This occurs inside the `Initialize` sub of the user form.  Here is some example code:

```
Private ClaimData As ClaimDataCls 'Class 1
Private Claims As Collection

Public Sub UserForm_Initialize
    Set ClaimData = New ClaimDataCls 'Class 1 initialization
    Set Claims = New Collection
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim Claim As ClaimsCls 'Class 2
    For Counter = 1 to 10
        Set Claim = New ClaimsCls '<-- Here is where Class 1 hits terminate
        'Put Data into Claim
        Claims.Add Claim
    Next Counter
```

I'm not calling terminate and I don't see how my original class is going out of scope here.  So whats the deal?

EDIT:  So I figured this out and posted the answer below to close the question.  It's a mess up on my part and you can read the details below.

Comment: I tried to recreate the behavior using the given code and 2 classes with nothing other than `Debug.Print "Class1 Init"` and similar statements in the `initalize` and `terminate` subs. Can you post your `Class_Terminate()` sub for `ClaimsCls` (Class 2)?

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've shown which could account for the behavior you're seeing, so there is likely some other code somewhere else which is the cause...

Comment: I figured it out.  It was an odd presentation of an error.  It was a completely unrelated error and I guess VBA just terminates any existing class instances before popping up the error message in this case, which I thought a bit odd.  But it was a good learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was that an exception was occurring in the initialize sub of user form I was using.  So here's the flow -> a button on a spreadsheet has one line of code to show the user form -> user form initialize starts and I initialize the class where the issue above was occuring -> there is an error in user form initialize (I attempted to set a property of an uninitialized object in the initialize sub) -> before displaying the error VBA, apparently, calls terminate on class file I was creating.

That was pretty much it.  I think it was just a somewhat unique combination of events that lead to the odd error presentation.  I'd delete the question since it wasn't what I'd consider a "fair" question, but it might be useful to someone at some point if they run into the same thing.